# Undeclared Identifier although it is declared

Tags: c, identifier, c89

for a program in which I try to create a file and later write into it, I have written the following:

```
 int main(){
        ...
        ....
       (some code)
        ....
          char DataBuffer[] = "This is the test file";
        ...
        ...


}
```

I get the error "DataBuffer: undeclared identifier" .
I am using Microsoft Visual C++ Express. And in an old asked question here in stackoverflow.com, I have read that Visual C++ uses an old C89 standard and that it does not support C99 standard. 
For that reason, I must declare the variables at the beginning(which I did for the rest of the parameters of CreateFile() and WriteFile). I mean, when you consider the following:

```
   DWORD dwCreationDisposition = CREATE_NEW;
```

Then I split it up and changed it to:

```
   DWORD dwCreationDisposition;
   ...
   dwCreationDisposition = CREATE_NEW
```

but I do not know how I should do it with an array. So, for example when I write:

```
 char DataBuffer[];
 ....
 DataBuffer[] = = "This is the test file";
```

Then I also get the same error message.
What can I do ? Is there any possibility to change the compiler options ? Or a chance to rewrite it such that the integrated compiler accepts it as the other splitted variables/parameters ?

best regards,

Comment: `char *DataBuffer; /* ... */ DataBuffer = "string"; `

Comment: You should be able to declare an init the variables in one statement still, albeit at the beginning of the scope. That said, you can also open a new scope using `{}` in order to declare a new variable there. Note that what @Mint97 suggests is different, because it declares a pointer to non-constant data which you still may not modify, while the original code declared a mutable array of chars.

Comment: "Undeclared Identifier although it is
identified" Did you mean "Undeclared Identifier although it is
declared?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your string to be re-writable you should so this:

```
 char DataBuffer[MAX_SIZE];
 ....
 strcpy(DataBuffer,"This is the test file");
```

Also consider using `strncpy` for avoiding buffer overrun error.

If your string is constant then:

```
const char DataBuffer[] = "This is the test file";
```